# selenium can't locate the element while the element is right there

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to using the selenium auto input the HTML code in  http://ueditor.baidu.com/website/examples/completeDemo.html. My procedure is that click the html first, and then code HTML in, while the IDE always told me that cant locate the element. it mad me crazy that the after click the [HTML Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drxZt.png), the element is right [there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMgCc.png), but always error on. i just wonder how can i write in box after click the HTML button by using selenium? thanks to the warm-hearted guy

```
import os,time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chromePath = r'E:/Python/WEB/web-infor-transfer/monidenglu/chromedriver.exe'
wd = webdriver.Chrome() 
loginUrl = 'http://ueditor.baidu.com/website/examples/completeDemo.html' 
wd.get(loginUrl) 


wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="edui4"]').click()


time.sleep(2)


wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="edui1_iframeholder"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]').send_keys('hello')

   time.sleep(5)
   wd.quit()
```

Comment: I can't get to the site.. is it in an IFRAME? Have you tried a wait?

Comment: I have no idea why you cant reach to the site, while thanks to you for taking your time on this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try action chains. For example - sending keys to the browser itself worked:

```
wd.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/pre[2]/span').click()
actions = ActionChains(wd)
actions.send_keys('hello')
actions.perform()
```

Comment: Greatly thank to you. It's really happy for me to see the code getting works. However, i use the right click and copy the xpath in Chrome like this "//*[@id="edui1_iframeholder"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/pre[2]", it's different from your xpath. i wonder that how you get the right xpath?

Comment: Same as you. Copy as xpath in firefox devtools.

Comment: That seem so strange, but whatever, thank you so much. It fixed!